# Objective-C: Asynchronous callback conditional checking

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, asynchronous, callback, objective-c-blocks

Is it something wrong with the `requestPanoramaNearCoordinate` Google maps SDK method? cause it get´s stuck in the `while loop`. I´v written the loop cause I want to wait with executing the rest of the method until the asynchronous callback method has completed. But the the while loop loops infinitely. Is it my code that´s simply wrong?

```
__block GMSPanorama *panPhoto = nil;
__block BOOL finished = NO;

[self.panoService requestPanoramaNearCoordinate:ranLatLng callback:^(GMSPanorama *panorama, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"panorama: %@ error: %@", panorama, error);
    panPhoto = panorama;
    finished = YES;
}];
while (!finished) {
    // Do nothing);
}
if (!panPhoto) return [self randomLatitudeLongitude];


return ranLatLng;
```

}

Comment: Forcing an asynchronous method to become synchronous is almost always a bad idea. Better get familiar with asynchronous methods!

Answer (score 1):

Why you launch async method and then doing loop? You must add block (with GMSPanorama argument) as parameter to your method and call this block inside `callback:^(GMSPanorama *panorama, NSError *error){`

Smth like that:

```
   - (void) methodNameWithBlock:(BlockName)block;

    __block GMSPanorama *panPhoto = nil;
    __block BOOL finished = NO;

    [self.panoService requestPanoramaNearCoordinate:ranLatLng callback:^(GMSPanorama *panorama, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"panorama: %@ error: %@", panorama, error);
        panPhoto = panorama;
        finished = YES;
        BlockName handler = [block copy];
        if (!ranLatLng){
           handler([self randomLatitudeLongitude])
        } else {
           handler(ranLatLng)
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: What should I put in BlockName?

Comment: You must create an block instance - 
typedef void(^MyBlockName)(GMSPanorama *panorama);
and put there your own MyBlockName. Like class name

Comment: And then there's no point of having those `__block` variables.